# Don't work dispatch_async in iOS 7 like in iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, grand-central-dispatch

There is a part of the program:

```
dispatch_sync (dispatch_get_main_queue (), ^ {
    [startBtn setTitle: @ "Loading ..." forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [self loadImages]; / / loading images - AssesLibrary
});

[self makeCollage];
NSLog (@ "Albums found:% lu", (unsigned long) [assetGroups count]);
```

from the block dispatch_sync program comes out, and I need to initially perform the functions of `[self loadImages]` (filled array of data), and then later performed `[self makeCollage]`.
If no `dispatch_sync` - then just `[self makeCollage]` starts filled without further processing array and gives an error.

Advise how to be

Comment: [iOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/iOS) is **not** [IOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cisco_IOS)!

Comment: are you calling `dispatch_sync` on the main thread? If yes, you are causing a deadlock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

added :

```
dispatch_queue_t currentQueue=dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0); 
dispatch_async(currentQueue, ^{ 

    __block UIImage *image=nil; 
    dispatch_sync(currentQueue, ^{ 

        //download the image here 
        image = [self loadImages];

    }); 

dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 

        //handle the image to the user here on the main queue 
        if (image != nil){ 
            [self makeCollage];
        } else 
        { 
            NSLog(@"Image isn't downloaded. Nothing to do."); 
        } 

    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, NULL), ^{
    // Do your stuff
});
```

Comment: Sorry if I comment, this is not totally correct. the global queue you are requesting runs on a background thread and the most of UIKit isn't thread safe. The dispatch async is correct, but the block should run on main queue.

Answer (score 0):

As Gabriele stated you are causing a dead lock. You got two options:

1. Create a new sync queue, but it seems that you are using UIKit in the block. UIKit for the most isn't thread safe particularly for part that has influence on the display
2. Instead on using a dispatch_sync, use a dispatch_async on the main queue

If you want to send work on a background thread you should organize your logic differently.